# having a subroutine wait for button input before ending the sub

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using a do while loop that after every loop, needs to ask the user what he/she wants to do next. The program is a pokemon style battle rpg, except for letting pokemon fight, you fight the monsters yourself.

What I am looking for is a pokemon/final fantasy style of fighting.

this is my sub that handles the battles:

```
  Private Sub Battle(ByVal Name As String, ByVal life As Integer, ByVal damage As Integer)

    lbl_MonsterName.Text = Name
    mobCurrHealth = mobMaxHealth
    lbl_MonsterHP.Text = mobCurrHealth & " / " & mobMaxHealth
    bar_monsterHP.Value = mobCurrHealth
    bar_monsterHP.Maximum = mobMaxHealth


    txtbx_Action.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "You find a " & Name)
    lbl_MonsterName.Visible = True
    lbl_MonsterHP.Visible = True
    bar_monsterHP.Visible = True

    wait(2000)

    txtbx_Action.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "What would you like to do?")
    btn_Attack.Visible = True
    btn_Run.Visible = True

'Here I want the program to wait for button input, but i still have to find a way to do that        


End Sub
```

After the line " What would you like to do", 2 (3) buttons will be visible:

- Attack
- Run
- (Inventory)

However, as you can see (and I do understand what is wrong, I just don't know how to fix it) my battle sub ends after the buttons are made visible.

I want the sub to wait until I have pressed either of these buttons are pressed and then act accordingly.

How can I do this?

---

Edit:

This is the code I use, where the sub "Battle"  is called:

```
   Private Sub btn_Adventure_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Adventure.Click

    btn_Adventure.Visible = False

    txtbx_Action.Visible = True

    Dim rng As New Random
    Dim MobGen As Integer = rng.Next(1, 4)

    Select Case MobGen

        Case 1
            mobName = "Rat"
            mobMaxHealth = 5
            mobDamage = 2
        Case 2
            mobName = "Bat"
            mobMaxHealth = 7
            mobDamage = 3
        Case 3
            mobName = "Snake"
            mobMaxHealth = 9
            mobDamage = 4
        Case 4
            mobName = "Wolf"
            mobMaxHealth = 11
            mobDamage = 5

    End Select

    txtbx_Action.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "You run around the forest trying to find something to kill")
    wait(1500)
    Battle(mobName, mobMaxHealth, mobDamage)


    btn_Adventure.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Also, if you think the way I am handling the program now is very wrong, please let me know how to improve it! This is a hobby project to try to learn the vb.net language a bit better, so any advice or constructive critisism  is verry appreciated!

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or something like it? Use events, don’t wait in a loop. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: DO it on Click Event of Button Click

Comment: @rynah It is vb.net. I want to manipulate VarA and VarB, but the way I want to manipulate them, depends on wich button is pressed

Comment: @Gutanoth: I understand that it’s VB.NET. Is this a Windows Forms Application? I’m just going to go ahead and assume it is.

Comment: @Gutanoth - Why you need to use .? you can achieve the same with Click wevent of Button.?

Comment: @rynah Oh yes sorry! it is.

Comment: Well Like I said, I have 3 (maybe 4) buttons. and I dont want the code to be dependent on just 1 button

Comment: You can use Form.ShowDialog(). Here Form contains Buttons. ON Button Click event you can close the Form.

Comment: @MayurBorad You mean that after the choice is given, it will open a new form with the buttons on it? I want this to only have 1 form where everything happens.. So this might be a last resort kind of solution

Comment: You can use event delegate for this purpose.

Comment: @MayurBorad How do I do that? (I am very new to vb.net and have never heard of it)

Comment: You may want to check out the solution I've linked to in my updated answer. There may be a simpler approach than the traditional state-based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've avoided binding and other things in this complete example to try to make it easier to understand and keep it as short as possible.

```
Public AllMobs As New List(Of Mob)
Public Player As Mob
Public CurrentMob As Mob
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AllMobs.Add(New Mob() With {.Name = "rat", .Damage = 2, .MaxHealth = 5, .CurrentHealth = 5})
    AllMobs.Add(New Mob() With {.Name = "bat", .Damage = 3, .MaxHealth = 7, .CurrentHealth = 7})
    AllMobs.Add(New Mob() With {.Name = "wolf", .Damage = 5, .MaxHealth = 11, .CurrentHealth = 11})
    Player = New Mob() With {.Name = "Gutanoth", .Damage = 1, .MaxHealth = 100, .CurrentHealth = 100}
    GetNextFight()
End Sub
Private Sub GetNextFight()
    If CurrentMob Is Nothing Then
        CurrentMob = SpawnMob()
        txtbx_Action.AppendText("You continue into the forest" & vbNewLine)
        txtbx_Action.AppendText(CurrentMob.Name + " is here" & vbNewLine)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub NextBattleAction()
   If Player.IsDead Then
        MessageBox.Show("You died. Lose!")
        Close()
    ElseIf CurrentMob.IsDead Then
        txtbx_Action.AppendText("---Victorious!" & vbNewLine)
        AllMobs.Remove(CurrentMob)
        CurrentMob = Nothing ' destroy mob object
    End If
    If AllMobs.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You've killed them all. Win!")
        Close()
    Else
        GetNextFight()
    End If
    If CurrentMob IsNot Nothing Then
        lbl_MonsterHP.Text = CurrentMob.CurrentHealth & " / " & CurrentMob.MaxHealth
    End If
End Sub
Private Function SpawnMob() As Mob
    If AllMobs.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing
    Dim rng As New Random
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer = rng.Next(AllMobs.Count)
    Return AllMobs(selectedIndex)
End Function
Private Sub btn_Attack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Attack.Click
    CurrentMob.Attack(Player)
    txtbx_Action.AppendText(CurrentMob.Name & " attacks" & vbNewLine)
    Player.Attack(CurrentMob)
    txtbx_Action.AppendText("you attack " & vbNewLine)
    NextBattleAction()
End Sub
Private Sub btn_Run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Run.Click
    txtbx_Action.AppendText("you run away" & vbNewLine)
    CurrentMob = Nothing ' make no current mob 
    GetNextFight()
End Sub
```

This should go in a separate Class file `Mob.vb`

```
Public Class Mob
    Property Name() As String
    Property MaxHealth() As Integer
    Property CurrentHealth() As Integer
    Property Damage As Integer
    Public Sub Attack(targetMob As Mob)
        targetMob.CurrentHealth = targetMob.CurrentHealth - Damage
    End Sub
    Public Function IsDead() As Boolean
        If CurrentHealth <= 0 Then Return True Else Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Looks like a great solution! could you please explain a bit closer what you are doing in the code?

Comment: you should be able to comment out your code in your main window and paste the above into it and it should work. You'll have to wire up that status labels and enable any buttons you disabled from the GUI

Comment: This is a more Object Oriented (OO) approach vs what you started with. The `Mob` class represents any character in your game (I've considered the player a `Mob` too as it makes things easier). It think it would be helpful for you to read a book about OO programming. Also you can set a break-point in my code and Debug->"Step Into" it to help understand what is happening. What specifically would you like explained?

Comment: It seems to me that when you "run" , it just starts a new fight (due to the GetNExtFight() ), is this true? I am unable to test the code atm because i dont have any sdk here

Comment: You can change what happens but currently when you run it leaves the current fight and randomly picks another mob from the `AllMobs` collection. Of course with only 3 mobs in the entire forest you might end up fighting the same one! I meant this as an example to get you started not the complete game ;)

Comment: Aah I see, thank you! I will use this in combination with other answers!

Comment: A good idea for an addition would be to create an `Item` Class (just the same way I did with the `Mob` class. You then can create a collection property in the `Mob` class `Public Inventory As List(Of Item)`. If you do that both the player and mobs will have the ability to store items and you can make logic to transfer the items on death.

Comment: Yes there are some other good answers here that could be combined to make the game even better. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE: Use `await`**

I am sitting in a TechEd seminar that suggests a potentially better way of handling this sort of situation: `async`. See the demo here: [Channel 9: Tip 3: Wrap events up in Task-returning APIs and await them](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Lucian03-TipsForAsyncThreadsAndDatabinding).

Basically, you can wrap an event in an `await` and then ask your UI thread to wait for the event to complete (without causing it to hang). This is a great way to storyboard without needing to keep track of complex state. It won't work in every scenario, but if it may be a significantly simpler alternative to the traditional state-based solution.

---

**State-based approach**

The way you are thinking about this is very intuitive, but it's not quite right. Programming in general can be thought of as transitioning between a series of different states. That is essentially what you are doing when showing and hiding various controls - implicitly transitioning from one state to the next.

I think it would be most helpful for you to make that implicit state-change explicit. You can define the different states your game can "rest" in, and then transition from one state to the next in response to user input.

So, for example, you might define a class-level property named CurrentState and an Enumeration with the various states you may wish to represent. Turning controls on and off can happen as a result of an event which fires when the game state changes.

With a CurrentState property, you can detect the state in which your game is in and respond differently to the same input (if that's an issue). Obviously I don't have access to your entire code, but hopefully you can find the code below inspiring. Realize that you will need to use your creative judgment: you should not necessarily copy-paste the code below and make your game fit into it.

The enumeration of your game states. Define this at the assembly level (outside of any classes):

```
Public Enum GameState
    Adventure
    Battle
    BattleCompleted
End Enum
```

Your game class (with the CurrentState property, a StateChanged event and stub methods showing one possible way of using the State):

```
Public Class Game

    ' This defines your custom event which will be
    ' raised when the CurrentState property changes
    Public Event GameStateChanged As EventHandler(Of GameStateChangedEventArgs)

    Private _currentState As GameState = GameState.Adventure
    Private Property CurrentState() As GameState
        Get
            Return _currentState
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As GameState)
            ' Don't raise GameStateChanged if setting the GameState to the same value
            If value = _currentState Then Exit Property

            ' If your application code changes the CurrentState
            ' property, raise the GameStateChanged event
            Dim l_oldState = _currentState
            _currentState = value
            RaiseEvent GameStateChanged(Me, New GameStateChangedEventArgs(l_oldState, _currentState))
        End Set
    End Property

    ' This is the event handler for your GameStateChanged event.
    ' When the game state changes, you can respond by updating the UI.
    Public Sub Game_GameStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GameStateChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.GameStateChanged
        If e.ToState = GameState.Adventure Then
            ' Turn on adventure mode buttons, etc
        ElseIf e.FromState = GameState.Adventure Then
            ' Turn off adventure mode buttons, etc
        End If
        If e.ToState = GameState.Battle Then
            ' Turn on battle monster controls, etc
        ElseIf e.FromState = GameState.Battle Then
            ' Turn off monster controls, etc
        End If
        If e.ToState = GameState.BattleCompleted Then
            ' Turn on post-battle controls, etc
        ElseIf e.FromState = GameState.BattleCompleted Then
            ' Turn off post-battle controls, etc
        End If
    End Sub

    ' Now, all you need to do is set the state of your game...
    Private Sub Adventure()
        Me.CurrentState = GameState.Adventure

        Battle()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Battle()
        Me.CurrentState = GameState.Battle

        ' Do the battle

        PostBattle()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PostBattle()
        Me.CurrentState = GameState.BattleCompleted
    End Sub

End Class
```

The StateChanged EventArgs class. This is completely optional, but gives you a little additional flexibility when handling state transitions.

```
Public Class GameStateChangedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Private _fromState As GameState
    Public ReadOnly Property FromState() As GameState
        Get
            Return _fromState
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _toState As GameState
    Public ReadOnly Property ToState() As GameState
        Get
            Return _toState
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal fromState As GameState, ByVal toState As GameState)
        _fromState = fromState
        _toState = toState
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is by no means the only way to go about the design of your program, but it is one helpful architecture when working in an event-based setting.

Answer (score 3):

Buttons events occur when you click the a button which is what it seems you're looking for.  I've actually started rewriting pokemon for my own growth and I use the button_click events.

Button_Click subs are subs that run when a button is clicked.  When a program is hovering, waiting for an input and a button is clicked, the program will jump into the sub associated with the button that was clicked.

In order to generate the "button_click" sub, you can double click a button when you're viewing the form to automatically generate the "Button_Click" sub.  There are other ways, but I personally find them trickier to use and more prone to mistakes.

What will happen here is your "Battle" sub will end and the battle will be set up.  The program will be hovering, waiting for something to happen.  When you click one of the buttons your program will jump into the sub for whatever button was clicked.  It does NOT require the program to be holding in a loop until a button is pressed, and you DON'T have to add any code to your existing battle sub (you can just let it end).

Here's a little example to help get you started.  The code that fills the button_click subs is something you'll tweak to your own purposes, but your setup should look very similar to this.  It's written is Visual Basic 2010 Express.

```
Private Sub btn_Attack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Attack.Click
    If mobCurrHealth > 0 And youCurrHealth > 0 Then
        'Both the monster and you are alive
        'Execute attack code
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Run_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Run.Click
    If mobCurrHealth > 0 And youCurrHealth > 0 Then
        'Both the monster and you are alive
        'Execute run code
    End If
End Sub
```

The important lines are the sub declaration lines which you'll probably automatically generate.  If you don't automatically generate your sub by double clicking the button, make sure that the "Handles" is set to the button you want to activate the sub followed by ".Click".  Whatever you want to happen once the button is pressed is up to you.  The above example checks to make sure both you and the monster are still alive, but it can be anything.

Good luck with your game development!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change your approach a little bit. You should think about each button doing a specific work and shouldn't wait for anyone.

On your btn_Adventure.Click should initialize the battle, not take care of it.

```
Private Sub btn_Adventure_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Adventure.Click

    GetModToAttack()
    InitialiseUI() ' Show the btnAttack, btnRun, show the "What would you like to do text", ...

End Sub
```

Now the UI will wait for the user input by itself, and when the user click on the button, you handle the action

```
Private Sub btn_Attack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Attack.Click

    ' Handle attack action
    ' Handle UI

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're lacking a basic understanding of how a Windows GUI program really works. When you include a line of code like:

```
button.Visible = true;
```

you're not actually making the button visible right then and there. What's going to happen is that the Windows Forms framework will set a flag indicating the button should be visible, then it's going to send a message to the button's message queue asking for the button to be redrawn. If the code is running from the UI thread, which appears to be the case here, it will have to pass control back to the operating system before such messages can be received and processed.

The main flaw in your approach is that you're trying to do everything within a single function. Realistically, you probably need to structure your entire program differently. **Cyborgx37** had the right basic idea in his answer, but maybe you didn't quite understand it.

The basic idea is that your program needs to have a variety of functions that are responsible for handling certain individual chunks of your overall game logic, and a collection of variables and data structures that define the game's current state at any given time.  And these functions need to properly take into account the way that GUI event handling works.

Let's walk though an overview. This is not exact, but in general should be pretty close to what you're wanting to do.

When you start a game, you would initialize the variables and data structures (hereafter referred to as "game state") in whatever fashion is appropriate for the start of a game.  This might include loading information from disk, from a database, or dynamically creating it via code. This would include graphics data, sound data, etc.

Next, you would create your game's display.  Be aware that creating the display and redrawing the display are two different things.

"Creating the display" means things like opening the window (if needed), adding any UI controls like buttons that you need, etc.

In comparison, "Redrawing the display" is the process of actually pushing the pixels around.  If your program uses graphics library calls to update anything on screen, your code will need to implement a function which will be called when your program receives a "PAINT" message.

Note that if you're doing a game strictly as a Windows GUI application, you may not need to explicitly create a "redraw screen" function. Generally if everything is drawn by the UI controls, you don't need one.

At this point, you probably want to force a screen redraw event. In a Windows GUI application this is normally done by sending an "Invalidate" message to the window. When this is processed, everything will be redrawn as needed. Things like standard UI controls will normally redraw themselves without any special action from your program.

Now is probably the point where you will need user input of some sort to proceed, even if it's just clicking "Start Game". If you have a selection of buttons, each button should be linked to an event handler function that contains the code specific to that particular selection. That code should update the game's variables and data structures as needed.

**Cyborgx37** showed an example where a single variable specified the game state. In practice, that variable will be the tip of the iceberg and there will be all sorts of other variables and data structures involved. The basic game state could indicate all sorts of things... like "Waiting for start" or "user pressed ATTACK".  Additional variables might indicate which monster is being attacked, what zone the player and monster are in, current health status of the player, etc.

All of the basic information that comes together to describe the "game state" probably wants to be organized together as a class. This should not include specifics about things like the UI setup which should be maintained separately.

If user input means something needs to change on screen, the event handler should update the game state and delete/add/change whatever UI controls are involved. You'll probably want a function that is capable of configuring the screen controls however needed for any particular game state. Make sure that those buttons are always configured with the proper event handler functions.

If the user input means that something dynamically drawn on screen needs an update, it should send an "Invalidate" message to the window (or to a specific control).

Your code sample had calls to **wait()** in a few places. This is usually the wrong way to do a pause, because you're stalling the entire thread. However, that doesn't mean the basic underlying idea is wrong. It's perfectly OK to want to have some certain amount of time between two things happening. That's where timers come in.

Timers allow you to update the game state as needed to respond to time passing. This could be needed for many reasons but for a game the most common would be animation. For example, maybe you have an image that needs to be animated 5 times per second. You would create a timer set to tick at 5hz, and in the event handler function, it would increment the animation frame index and then send "Invalidate" message to the window or control with the image.

You can have multiple timers set to different frequencies, but it's best to combine things where possible.  If you have a dozen different things on screen that need to be animated, use a single timer where the handler function checks each item separately.

There's a lot more involved, but those are the basics I think you need to get onto the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Make `VarA` and `VarB` class-level:

```
Private VarA, VarB As Integer ' Or whatever type
```

Then add a function for the beginning logic of the loop:

```
Private Sub NextIteration() ' Give this a better name, or even make it part of Update
    If VarA <= 0 OrElse VarB <= 0 Then
        ' Loop’s over; hide the buttons or something
    Else
        Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

Then handle all the action buttons separately, perform the actions, and call `NextIteration()` at the end of each `Click` handler. Call `NextIteration()` to start.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really Novice. I found a real world example!

Take a pokemon game for example! untill either pokemon is dead you press a button -> an action happens. is either pokemon dead? no? press a button -> do an action.

I need a simple way to do this kind of operation

Comment: This is the simplest way. =)

Comment: Sorry for being so non-understanding. Where do I check wich button is pressed? and where do I do my action that goes with the button?

Comment: @Gutanoth: You don’t even have to check; just perform the action in each button’s `Click` handler. (Double-click on the button in design mode.)

Comment: This does not work :( I have edited my code in the startpost to make it more clear how my project is atm.